# How to use views to make queries on the webform (or entityform) results and show in a node?

Tags: views, webforms, entities

Do you know how to use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (or any other "query builder") to filter/query the submissions made either by webform or entityform?

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of webform (7.x-4.0-alpha10) allows views to display webform submissions right out of the box. Although you cannot revert to an older version after upgrading to 4.x, so it's important to back up your database. But after you have 4.x installed, you will see an option when you create a new view to show content of type "webform submissions". You can also read up on how to accomplish the task in older versions of webform here: https://drupal.org/node/1658784